# React Native -- How to edit the value of dynamically generated TextInput fields?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to edit the value of the dynamically generated TextIput fields value.

Here is my JSON array

```
{
    "measurements": [{
        "id": 200,
        "sub_type_id": 34,
        "sub_type": "TOPS SL",
        "measurement_input": "15"
    }, {
        "id": 201,
        "sub_type_id": 47,
        "sub_type": "TOPS ABOVE CHEST",
        "measurement_input": "40"
    }, {
        "id": 202,
        "sub_type_id": 48,
        "sub_type": "TOPS CHEST",
        "measurement_input": "42"
    }]
}
```

base on the above JSON array data I have created TextInputs dynamically but the problem is I am not able to edit the TextInputs values.

Code for creating TextInput

```
     ....
     this.state = {
         ...
         subtypes: props.route.params.editdata.measurements,
         inputData: [],
         ...
     }
     ...

     {this.state.subtypes.map((inputs, idx) => {
                    return (
                      <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 2, margin: 10}}>
                        <Text style={{margin: 2}}>{inputs.sub_type}</Text>
                        <View
                          style={{
                            flex: 1,
                            flexDirection: 'row',
                            alignItems: 'center',
                          }}>
                          <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                            <TextInput
                              style={styles.textInput}
                              placeholder={inputs.sub_type}
                              value={inputs.measurement_input} //<------ value not able to change
                              onChangeText={(text) =>
                                this.addValues(text, idx, inputs.sub_type_id)
                              }
                            />
                          </View>
                        </View>
                      </View>
                    );
                  })}
```

This is the function for taking value from TextInput.

```
//------ HERE I am not able to do editable parts --------
  addValues = (text, index, id) => {
    let dataArray = this.state.inputData;
    let checkBool = false;
    if (dataArray.length !== 0) {
      dataArray.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.index === index) {
          element.measurement_input = text;
          element.sub_type_id = id;
          checkBool = true;
        }
      });
    }
    if (checkBool) {
      this.setState({
        inputData: dataArray,
      });
    } else {
      dataArray.push({measurement_input: text, index: index, sub_type_id: id});
      this.setState({
        inputData: dataArray,
      });
    }
  };
```

I tried many technics but not able to perform the value editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it using only two lines of code.

it doesn't need to copy the updated values in another array (`inputData` state array). Just only update to the same array (`subtypes` state array that contains my actual edited json data) and I used `this.forceUpdate();` javascript function.

Here is the updated code, all the updated values will contain in the `this.state.subtypes` .

```
    {this.state.subtypes.map((inputs, idx) => {
                        return (
                          <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 2, margin: 10}}>
                            <Text style={{margin: 2}}>{inputs.sub_type}</Text>
                            <View
                              style={{
                                flex: 1,
                                flexDirection: 'row',
                                alignItems: 'center',
                              }}>
                              <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                                <TextInput
                                  style={styles.textInput}
                                  placeholder={inputs.sub_type}
                                  value={inputs.measurement_input}
                                  onChangeText={(text) =>
                                    {
//this.addValues(text, idx,inputs.sub_type_id, inputs.measurement_input)  //<----- no need
                                   
    
                                    // these two line of codes work out 
                                    this.state.subtypes[idx].measurement_input = text
                                    this.forceUpdate();
                                    }
                                  }
                                />
                              </View>
                            </View>
                          </View>
                        );
                      })}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using this.state.subtypes to render and set state on inputData?

Comment: Hii Wei Yan. Welcome to StackOverflow. I think you should comment on my question. I edited my question and add more info, JSON data is set to subtypes and inputData will be used to store edited data.

Comment: @RaikumarKhangembam Sorry,  it seems like I am not able to comment under the question since I am new to StackOverflow. 
May I ask that how did you judge the data haven't been write into the inputData please? Through console.log or render on other components?

Comment: I made it work in another simple way. I gave the answer.